# When I try to open a sheet from an android emulator , I get Unable to access document. Please make sure that you are connected to the internet

Tags: android, google-sheets, android-emulator

I created the sheet and can append to it using the app in the emulator.  I am using an ACTION_VIEW intent with an url.  Seems to work on a real device.  If I try an intent to another address in the emulator it works.

```
 String url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + mSpreadsheetId + "/edit#gid=0";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
```

I suspect the code does not clarify much.  I have enough security to create and add to the sheet in the same app with an emulator. I obviously have internet.  Am I missing a setting on Google sheets or something?

All I am trying to do is test on older sdk's.  this test is on api level 24 with the latest playstore libraries and the google sheets api.  But none of that has anything to do with this intent.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. Use code sample from where you think the problem might be along with any error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the emulator needed the Google sheets app installed.  Whatever was launched for this intent was using the wrong url. For some reason I was under the impression that the intent launched a browser window.